# Override AngularJS Default Email Validator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I want to override email validator of AngularJS. I want it to use my custom string, to validate email address. 
The code I found in their documentation is like this:
    JS:

```
   var app = angular.module('registrationApp', []);

    app.directive('overwriteEmail', function() {
      var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@example\.com$/i;

      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: '',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {

                // this will overwrite the default Angular email validator
                ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
                    return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="registrationApp" data-ng-init="">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
      Overwritten Email:
      <input type="email" ng-model="myEmail" overwrite-email name="overwrittenEmail" />
      <span ng-show="form.overwrittenEmail.$error.email">This email format is invalid!     </span><br>
      Model: {{myEmail}}
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

But the code does not work. The error thrown is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
>       at link (http://localhost:63342/goga_tests/js/registration.js:39:32)
>       at N (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:54:372)
>       at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:47:256)
>       at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:47:273)
>       at N (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:54:313)
>       at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:47:256)
>       at N (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:54:313)
>       at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:47:256)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:46:377
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:18:314

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: may be you need to write terminal: true, priority:1001 inside you directive

Comment: When I add them both, it gives such error:

 Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=overwriteEmail
    at Error (native)
... etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

angular version `1.2.26` that you are using does not add [`$validators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators) special property on the ngModel controller instance. You need 1.3.x version of angular.

Provided you have 1.3.x you can just use your directive as is, and you can add priority `2` to be greater than ng-model (which is 1) so that your directive sets the validator before `ng-model` directive takes its turn :

```
app.directive('overwriteEmail', function() {
  var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@example\.com$/i;

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: '',
    priority: 2,
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {
        // this will overwrite the default Angular email validator
        ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
          return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('overwriteEmail', function() {
  var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@example\.com$/i;

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: '',
    priority: 1,
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {
        // this will overwrite the default Angular email validator
        ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
          return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
      <div>
        Overwritten Email:
        <input type="email" ng-model="myEmail" overwrite-email name="overwrittenEmail" />
        <span ng-show="form.overwrittenEmail.$error.email">This email format is invalid!     </span>
        <br>Model: {{myEmail}}
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also stick with using `ng-pattern` and use `form.overwrittenEmail.$error.pattern` to display the message if invalid pattern.

```
<input type="email" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@example\.com$/i" 
                    ng-model="myEmail" name="overwrittenEmail" />
   <span ng-show="form.overwrittenEmail.$error.pattern">
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
      <div>
        Overwritten Email:
        <input type="email" ng-model="myEmail" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@example\.com$/i" name="overwrittenEmail" />
        <span ng-show="form.overwrittenEmail.$error.pattern">This email format is invalid!     </span>
        <br>Model: {{myEmail}}
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks mate! That solved the problem! I just replaced angular with newer version and added priority : > thanks a lot again!